# How does Wolverine survive even his bones are adamantium?

Tags: marvel, wolverine

How is Wolverine able to survive?  The main source of blood is bone marrow. But his bones are adamantium - Even if we assume that his bones are covered with adamantium, how does he get blood?

Answer (score 4):

Wolverine's bones are not made of adamantium, they are *coated* in adamantium. Underneath the metal are normal (well, mutant) living bone tissue.

Any possibly harmful side-effects of this process would be counteracted by his healing factor. In fact, it's pretty well known that his healing factor is *the only* reason he survived the process. We don't know exactly what that entails, but it might mean that Wolverine's body is able to regenerate blood cells outside of his bone marrow. Or, his blood vessels may have regenerated *through* the adamantium while it was still liquid, meaning he still has normal blood flow to his bone marrow.

Comment: Hmmm..thanks.the explanation is good ..,